# Вывод результата выполнения программы в файл c#

Tags: c#

Задача следующая

Я открываю консольную программу из кода командой Process.Start("Out.exe"); Как перенаправить результат выполнения в файл?

Out.exe я получаю после компиляции какого-то кода из программы следующим кодом

```
string Output = "Out.exe";
            String[] str = new String[2];
            System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();//Параметры компиляции
            //Make sure we generate an EXE, not a DLL
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;//Создать exe файл
            parameters.OutputAssembly = Output;// Имя exe файла
            CompilerResults results = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, source);//Скомпилировать его с заданными параментами
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос решен следующим способом

```
 // Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the output stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the output stream first and then wait.
 string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Нашел на msdn